# Deleting Blob (App Engine NDB)

Tags: app-engine-ndb

How can I delete a blob from the blobstore ***and its corresponding BlobKeyProperty from the datastore***? I've implemented my solution as below, however, while the blob is successfully deleted from the blobstore, the BlobKeyProperty from the datastore is not cleared (ie: companyPerson.profile_pic_blobkey = SOME_RANDOM_STRING here instead of None).

The model file:

```
class CompanyPerson(ndb.Model):
    profile_pic_blobkey = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
```

Handler:

```
from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import BlobInfo
....
blob_info = BlobInfo.get(companyPerson.profile_pic_blobkey)
blob_info.delete()
```

*Edit*: **Somewhat Solved**:-

Well I've got it sorted out, though I don't know if it's the best way since most online references don't mention this step. But basically what I did was to insert

```
profile_pic_blobkey = None
```

right after blob_info.delete().